# Sets measurable in every affine subspace

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Take a non-measurable subset $S\subseteq [-1,1]$ and subtract $S\times \{0\}$ from the unit disk $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The set $X=B\setminus (S\times \{0\})$ is measurable by 2-D Lebesgue measure because the part on the real line has 2-D measure 0. I don't want this situation.

My request is: is there a name for subsets $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $X\cap L$ is measurable in $L$ (according to the dimension of $L$) for every affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: So you do allow, for example, a non-measurable (according to arc length)subset of a circle, since that meets each line in at most $2$ points ... ?  I am not aware of such a name.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set

Comment: You might get some ideas here: Anderson, Robert & Zame, William. (2001). Genericity with Infinitely Many Parameters. Advances in Theoretical Economics. 1. 1003-1003. 10.2202/1534-5963.1003. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4909286_Genericity_with_Infinitely_Many_Parameters